# How to reference webpage title from web.config file?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is there a simple way of referencing the page header title from web.congfig file?

```
<title runat="server"><%$ AppSettings:HeaderTitle %>"</title>
```

this gives complying error

and when I use label like :

```
<title runat="server"><asp:Label ID="MainTitle" runat="server" Text="<%$ AppSettings:HeaderTitle %>" /></title>
```

then the result contains span element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `Literal` control - it won't output any tags at all:

```
<title runat="server">
    <asp:Literal ID="MainTitle" runat="server" Text="<%$ AppSettings:HeaderTitle %>" />
</title>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and I really respect the people those were coding before internet :)

Comment: @akdurmus: we read books, and the contents of things like the MSDN library were available on CD-ROM.

Comment: We even had to buy those books at (gasp!) STORES! No, really!